# If I have two coordinates of a point anywhere, how can I find two other points in that line that make up the middle third?

Tags: math, trigonometry

Say I have a line coor1: (0,300) coor2: (600,300)

With that, I want to find the 2 middle third points which would be (200,300) (400,300)

Normally, I'd do something like:

```
x = (xCoor2 - xCoor1) * (1.0/3.0) + xCoor1;
y =  yCoor1 - (yCoor1 - yCoor2) * (1.0/3.0);
```

But that would only work successfully in some cases. I need one statement that can find those 2 points when coor1 and coor2 are anywhere. Such as coor1: (400,400) coor2: (600,600)

Comment: This question seems to be purely about a math problem, and is language-agnostic.

Comment: That's not a programming question, but a rather basic math question.

Comment: Clearly not a programming question, but he now has his answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

```
Point left{0.0,300.0}, right{600.0,300.0}, one_third, two_thirds;

one_third = left + (right - left) *1.0/3.0;
two_thirds= left + (right - left) *2.0/3.0;
```

or more explicitly

```
one_third.x = left.x + (right.x - left.x) *1.0/3.0;
one_third.y = left.y + (right.y - left.y) *1.0/3.0;
two_thirds.x= left.x + (right.x - left.x) *2.0/3.0;
two_thirds.y= left.y + (right.y - left.y) *2.0/3.0;
```

Comment: Or more general `i_th_n_th.x = first.x + (last.x -first.x) * i / n`